# Insert python binary string object in MySQL blob

Tags: python, mysql

I'd like to insert a string object containing binary data into a MySQL blob column. However, I keep getting MySQL syntax errors.

I made a small script for debugging purposes:

```
import MySQLdb
import array
import random

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="u", passwd="p", db="cheese")
cur = conn.cursor()

a = array.array('f')
for n in range(1,5):
    a.append(random.random())
bd = a.tostring()
print type(bd) # gives str
query = '''INSERT INTO cheese (data) VALUES (%s)''' % bd
cur.execute(query)
```

Result (but not every time...)

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?fJ\x95<=  
\xad9>\xf3\xec\xe5>)' at line 1")
```

The problem apparently boils down to certain characters in the binary data which MySQL doesn't like. Is there a fail-safe way of putting binary data into the MySQL database?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do it this way, instead:

```
query = '''INSERT INTO cheese (data) VALUES (%s)'''
cur.execute(query, (bd,))
```

Instead of doing Python-level string formatting, this uses MySQL-specific formatting, including escaping characters that have special meaning to MySQL in strings that are to be embedded in queries.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work! I really don't understand the underlying principle though. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of doing Python-level string formatting, this uses MySQL-specific formatting, including escaping characters that have special meaning to MySQL in strings that are to be embedded in queries.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not related to the formating of the string, but the an SQL syntax.
So I guess the problem is with the SQL query itself, not the characters.
Use `query = '''INSERT INTO cheese (data) VALUES ('%s')''' % bd` Where you enclose the string in question in a single quote.

Comment: I already tried different type of quotes in different combinations, so that wasn't the issue.